# Using Celery With ActiveMQ

Tags: docker-compose, celery, activemq-classic

I am trying to queue up celery tasks based on messages that are coming in on an ActiveMQ instance. I am able to hook celery up to rabbitMQ just fun and have my tasks execute based on messages, but if I were to switch to activeMQ, I get the following error from the activeMQ instance:

```
Transport Connection to: <VARIOUS DIFFERENT ENDPOINTS> failed: Connection from client using unsupported AMQP attempted
```

Using docker-compose, the app build is very simple and looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  activemq:
    image: webcenter/activemq:latest
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
    environment:
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'amqp://guest:guest@activemq:5672//'
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - activemq
```

I assume since activeMQ is just a AMQP protocol, it should easily be integrated, but most sources seem to favor rabbitMQ. Has anyone been successful in this endeavor?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ is not just an AMQP protocol, it is a multi protocol messaging broker and its default protocol is the Openwire protocol.  The ActiveMQ broker requires you to configure an AMQP transport connector in order for a client to speak AMQP to it.  In the above configuration it looks like you configured some ports which would normally be the Web Console port and the default Opwneire port on an ActiveMQ broker.

I don't know anything about Celery so I can't speak to what exactly you need to configure it but I'd guess you need to give it a client URL for the default openwire based client "tcp://activemq:61616" or something along those line or configure somehow an AMQP transport connector on port 5672.